# PHP require_once fails but require works

Tags: php, require-once

In an application I am calling require_once $file where I have validated that the $file variable represents an absolute path, the file exists, and is readable.   PHP 7.3 is giving me the dreaded:  "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required" message.

When I change the code to use "require" instead of "require_once" I get further,  till the next "require_once" statement.

I am running PHP 7.2.19 on ubuntu 18.04.

This particular code is embedded deep within an application that has already included and required many different files at different times.

I have checked for obvious things like the particular file being included multiple times (it is not)... and including a different file for testing purposes,  and that also consistently fails.   I have double checked permissions, etc.

```php
$file = "$destdir/lib/include.php";
$file = realpath($file);
if( is_file($file) && is_readable($file) ) {
    require_once $file;  // fails
    // require $file;  // works, but fails when require_once is called within this file.
    // include $file;   // works, but fails when require_once is called within this file
    // include_once $file; // fails
}


I expected of course, that the file is required.
```

Comment: `print_r($file)` is the path definitely correct?

Comment: You sure it's not a `require_once` from inside the `include.php` file that is failing?

Comment: Check for @MER suggestion. Also, the fatal error always point to a line and file where the error occurs. Show it to us.

Comment: I found the issue.  was related to opcode cache.   disabling the opcode cache solved the issue.